# How do I elegantly finalize objects that own threads and raise events?

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety, .net-2.0

The question is about what to do when the caller *forgets* to dispose of my object. Thus I've skipped implementing `IDisposable` for brevity. My questions are: **How dangerous is the last code sample?** Can it be improved? Or maybe I'm obsessing over elegance too much? Or maybe there's another pattern to do this better already?

The story begins with an attempt to wrap some long running process so it an be safely accessed from the main thread.

```
Public Class ThisCantRaiseEvents
    Private client As UdpClient

    Public Sub New(ByVal client As UdpClient)
        Me.client = client
        Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf DoWork)
        thread.IsBackground = True
        thread.Start(client)
    End Sub

    Public Event PacketReceived As EventHandler

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        client.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub DoWork(ByVal state As Object)
        Dim client As UdpClient = DirectCast(state, UdpClient)
        Try
            While True
                client.Receive(Nothing)
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The naive attempt at dispatching events to the main thread. Works well but never goes out of scope because its own thread keeps it alive. (Remember, threads don't die if their Thread object goes out of scope.)

```
Public Class ThisWillLeak
    Private client As UdpClient
    Private mainThread As Control

    Public Sub New(ByVal client As UdpClient, ByVal control As Control)
        Me.client = client
        Me.mainThread = control
        Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf DoWork)
        thread.IsBackground = True
        thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Event PacketReceived As EventHandler

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        client.Close()
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPacketReceived(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent PacketReceived(Me, e)
    End Sub

    ' The worker thread has a pointer to ThisWillLeak
    ' and so it will live forever!
    Private Sub DoWork(ByVal state As Object)
        Try
            While True
                client.Receive(Nothing)
                mainThread.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of EventArgs) _
                (AddressOf OnPacketReceived), EventArgs.Empty)
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

' This was my first attempt at solving the problem in the previous sample. Alas, it get very ugly very quickly as the DoWork method becomes more complex.

```
Public Class ThisIsVeryUgly
    Private client As UdpClient
    Private mainThread As Control

    Public Sub New(ByVal client As UdpClient, ByVal control As Control)
        Me.client = client
        Me.mainThread = control
        Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf DoWork)
        thread.IsBackground = True
        thread.Start(New WeakReference(Me))
    End Sub

    Public Event PacketReceived As EventHandler

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        client.Close()
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPacketReceived(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent PacketReceived(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub DoWork(ByVal state As Object)
        Dim weakThis As WeakReference = DirectCast(state, WeakReference)
        Dim this As ThisIsVeryUgly = DirectCast(weakThis.Target, ThisIsVeryUgly)
        Dim client As UdpClient = this.client
        this = Nothing
        Try
            While True
                client.Receive(Nothing)
                this = DirectCast(weakThis.Target, ThisIsVeryUgly)
                this.mainThread.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of EventArgs) _
                (AddressOf this.OnPacketReceived), EventArgs.Empty)
                this = Nothing
                ' Repeat for every other place we need to raise an event! Ugh!
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my newest invention. It's elegant but has the potential to cause problems because the `sender` argument of the events it raises is not what the user would expect. **Can this cause me any problems?**

```
Public Class ThisIsAlmostGood
    Private client As UdpClient
    Private worker As WorkThread

    Public Sub New(ByVal client As UdpClient, ByVal mainThread As Control)
        Me.client = client
        worker = New WorkThread(client, mainThread)
    End Sub

    Public Custom Event PacketReceived As EventHandler
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            AddHandler worker.PacketReceived
        End AddHandler
        RemoveHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler)
            RemoveHandler worker.PacketReceived
        End RemoveHandler
        RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event

    Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        client.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Class WorkThread
        Private client As UdpClient
        Private mainThread As Control

        Public Sub New(ByVal client As UdpClient, ByVal mainThread As Control)
            Me.client = client
            Me.mainThread = mainThread
            Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf DoWork)
            thread.IsBackground = True
            thread.Start()
        End Sub

        Public Event PacketReceived As EventHandler

        Protected Overridable Sub OnPacketReceived(ByVal e As EventArgs)
            ' But the user expects a pointer to ThisIsAlmostGood,
            ' not WorkThread! Should I pass Nothing instead?
            RaiseEvent PacketReceived(Me, e)
        End Sub

        Private Sub DoWork(ByVal state As Object)
            Try
                While True
                    client.Receive(Nothing)
                    mainThread.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of EventArgs) _
                    (AddressOf OnPacketReceived), EventArgs.Empty)
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: You have posted a massive amount of code. If you can summarize this with a simple code sample, you will be more likely to get good answers.

Comment: This already is the least amount of code I could come up with while not losing context.

Comment: Only a comment.  What does this code do?  Could it implemented as WCF service?

Comment: It fires an event when it receives a packet. But that is beside the point. This code is just an illustration of my problem. An example. It's not *real* code.